# How do I display RSS news feed?

Tags: javascript, rss

I'm playing around and trying to add news feed to a website, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I got http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=yhoo that I want to display, and I used https://surfing-waves.com/feed.htm to get the code output.

I copy pasted the code into the body of my HTML code and all it displays is a string "powered by Surfing Waves" basically. I'm not sure what I'm missing here to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

In the code generated by this widget, change

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script>`

to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script>`